# Unable to detect contact of SKSpritNode (Swift Xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skspritenode

I have a simple game which I am coding for iOS with Swift. In the game, the character needs to collect items. I have the following set up in a Swift file for for the main player:

```
import SpriteKit

struct ColliderType {
    static let Player: UInt32 = 1
    static let Ground: UInt32 = 2
    static let Collectables: UInt32 = 3
}

class Player: SKSpriteNode {

    func initialize() {

        var walk = [SKTexture]()

        for i in 1...16 {
            let name = "Kidwalk\(i)"
            walk.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))
        }

        let walkAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: walk, timePerFrame: 0.095, resize: true, restore: true)

        self.name = "Player"
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: self.size)
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Player
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Ground | ColliderType.Collectables
        self.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.zPosition = 5
        self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(walkAnimation))
        self.xScale = CGFloat(0.4)
        self.yScale = CGFloat(0.4)
    }

    func jump() {
        self.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        self.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 500))
    }

}
```

In the main GameplayScene.swift file I have set up the following constant:

```
let phone = SKSpriteNode()
```

And then I create the object as follows:

```
func createPhone() {
     var ring = [SKTexture]()

     for i in 1...7 {
     let name = "phone\(i)"
     ring.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))
     }

     let ringAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: ring, timePerFrame: 0.095, resize: true, restore: true)

     phone.name = "Phone"
     phone.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: phone.size.width / 2, height: phone.size.height / 2))
     phone.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
     phone.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
     phone.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Player
     phone.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Ground | ColliderType.Collectables
     phone.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: -50)
     phone.zPosition = 5
     phone.run(SKAction.repeatForever(ringAnimation))
     phone.xScale = CGFloat(0.7)
     phone.yScale = CGFloat(0.7)

        let move = SKAction.moveTo(x: -(self.frame.size.width * 2), duration: 15)

        let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move, remove])

        phone.run(sequence)

        addChild(phone)
    }
```

I am calling createPhone() in the didMove function at the top.

And finally I have this setup for the collision detecting:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody();
        var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody();

        if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "Player" {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA;
            secondBody = contact.bodyB;
        } else {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB;
            secondBody = contact.bodyA;
        }

        if firstBody.node?.name == "Player" && secondBody.node?.name == "Ground" {
            canJump = true;
            print("canjump")
        } else if firstBody.node?.name == "Player" && secondBody.node?.name == "Phone" {
            print("Collect)
        }
    }
```

Clearly there is something fundamentally wrong because the collision between the ground and the player is detected but the one between the phone and the player is not.

I believe I have the struct set up correctly and I've checked through the collision bit masks and categories of all the nodes and I cannot work out where I'm going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, your phone is a player

Comment: Finally, you never set contactBitMask, only collision

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have looked up bit masks and I've had it working on other apps but just am having a blank here. I've added contactBitMask to the phone and set it to ColliderType.Player and the same for the player to ColliderType.phone but still no joy. What did you mean by my phone being a player?

Comment: No confrontation from me. Quite the opposite. I have read up on them and thought I understood but clearly I haven't and was looking for some advice. Anyway, will close the topic now.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)